# jquery dynamic table render properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery, I am trying to display dynamic table with jquery.
But when I call below

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
    value_split = value.slice(',');
    for(var i=0;i<value_split.length;i++){
        $("#table").append("<tr><td>" + value_split[i] + "</td></tr>");
    }
});
```

I am splitting because it's comma separated list. I get data like

```
First name
Last Name
Age
Sam
Don
23
```

How can I get in proper format with 3 headers and details in below row like normal table

yes I'm slicing becuase `data` is object e.g. `Object {headers: Array[6], values: Array[6]}`

sorry it's object not list

Comment: Can you paste some of your CSV data?

Comment: _I am splitting because it's comma separated list_ where is the list

Comment: You're not splitting, it looks like you're slicing a string, so how you'd get those results are unclear ?

Comment: If there are no 'returns', you'll struggle. There are libs out there that will do this, but the csv will still need row separation. By 'return', I mean does the csv contain \r\n or similar to separate the rows?

Comment: updated data details

Comment: Why not show us what `data` really is? You can't slice an object, and you use `slice(',')` which would indicate that you've mistyped, as `slice` accepts numbers for the start and end position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted to create the row outside the inner loop, otherwise you'll get a new row for each value you append.

```js
var data = [
    "Sam, Don, 23",
    "Jane, Doe, 40"
];

jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
    var value_split = value.split(',');
    var tr = $('<tr />');
    
    for(var i=0;i<value_split.length;i++){
        tr.append( $('<td />', {text : value_split[i]}) );
    }
    
    $("#table").append(tr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
</table>
```